# Copy group of objects in sketch makes it invisible

Tags: sketch-app

I am beginning with sketch.

I don't know what happens in my document, you may have a clue. I have a group of objects (originally an `.eps` file) in a sketch document.

If I copy and paste it into my working document, it is pasted but "invisible". If I ungroup it, it becomes visible. It I group it agin, it becomes again invisible.

Do you a clue of what I am missing here?

Thanks!

---

#### EDIT

I have encountered again the same problem... and this solution didn't work.

---

Go to `View > Show Layer List`, remove the "Clip" thing (I don't know what it is) :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without seeing your document. Three possibilities immediately come to mind.

### Clipping mask

If the objects are pasted at a point in the layers where they are effected by a mask, they'll only appear if they fall within the visible bounds. This is what a mask looks like in the layers list.

[image: Layer group with a mask layer]

Everything within the top group will be cropped by the mask layer. If you ungroup the layers, the mask will be disabled.

### Artboard bounds

Another type of masking that can bite you if you're not familiar with Sketch is grouped objects that fall out of the artboard's bounds. The artboard becomes a mask, just as if the object were partially over-hanging the bounds.

[image: Object cropped by artboard bounds]

If you ungroup an object that lies entirely on the "pasteboard" (or if it was never in a group in the first place), Sketch will move it out of the artboard group so that it is not masked.

### Sketch is glitchy

There's always the possibility that copying in an antique format like EPS may just be causing problems. Sketch has definitely taken the `just ship it` approach to development. They have a pretty focused use case (interface design) and they often break other workflows in the process of innovating.

[image: Homer finds a bug]

Comment: You can try with the files from [there](http://www.freepik.com/free-vector/circle-seamless-pattern_711507.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the object 'disappearing". Scroll down to Ignore Underlying Mask. Worked for me.